# MySQL SQL STATE[HY000] [1203] User XXXXX already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I noticed that my return value from $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) is:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User *USERNAMEHERE* already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`

All my queries are successful and everything seems to be working fine.

I thought I was properly closing the connections by assigning it NULL. Here is my function, any ideas why I'm maxing out?

```
function mysql_read_single_row($sql, $array_of_values) {

    try {
        //create a connection
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=".CONST_MYSQL_HOST.";dbname=".CONST_MYSQL_DBNAME, CONST_MYSQL_RUSER, CONST_MYSQL_RPASS);

        //set the sql
        $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);

        //execute query
        $STH->execute($array_of_values);  
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }

    $return_row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //close the connection
    $STH = null;
    $DBH = null;

    //strip any escaped quotes from the data
    $return_row = array_map('stripslashes', $return_row);

    //return the array
    return $return_row;
}
```

Is setting $STH and $DBH to null not sufficient to prevent this error?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#connection

Answer (score 0):

In your php ini file you can increase MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS and MAX_CONNECTIONS

Or you can try to use this SQL command:

```
GRANT ALL * TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to increase MySql connections
Ref: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-increase-max-connections-in-mysql/

1. Check the default max connections
   Log into MySQL command line tool and run the following command to get the current default max connections supported by your database server.

   mysql> show variables like "max_connections";

You will see the following output.

```
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 100   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Bonus Read : How to Change MySQL Timezone in Query

2. Increase Max Connections
   There are two ways to increase MySQL connections. Here’s the command to update max connections to 200 via MySQL command line tool without restart.

   mysql> set global max_connections = 200;

The above command will increase max connections without restart but once the server is restarted, the changes will be gone. This method is useful to increase available connections in a production system such as a website/app, without having to restart your database server.

To permanently increase max connections, open my.cnf file,

```
$ sudo vi /etc/my.cnf
```

Depending on your Linux distribution and type of installation, my.cnf file may be located at any of the following locations.

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
~/.my.cnf
```

Add the following line under [mysqld] section.

```
max_connections = 200
```

Now if you restart MySQL server, the changes will persist.

3. Restart MySQL Server
   Restart MySQL Server to apply changes

   $ sudo service mysql restart